# how to add path of libraries to vscode python project

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm working on a project in vscode on macOS and I need a library for the project. And I notice the library is already installed on other paths.

```
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (4.9.3)
Requirement already satisfied: soupsieve>1.2 in /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from beautifulsoup4) (2.2.1)
```

how can I make python on vscode to consider these paths when looking for the modules?

Answer (score 0):

It might be that VSCode is not using the right environment.

To choose the right virtual environment, open command palette (ctrl+shift+p) and type `Python: Select Interpreter`. Or, you could click on the `python version` information at the bottom left of your screen.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can switch to the `anaconda3` environment as `PreciXon` has mentioned.

If you don't want, it's recommended to install the packages again into the environment you are using now.

And if you just want to reuse these packages and do not want to switch the environment, you can add these paths into the `PYTHONPATH`.

You can do this to modify the `PYTHONPATH`:

1. Add these in the settings.json file to Modify the `PYTHONPATH` in the terminal:

   **"terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
   "PYTHONPATH": "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages"
   }**
2. Create a `.env` file under your workspace, and add these settings in it to modify the `PYTHONPATH` for the extension and debugger:

   **PYTHONPATH=/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages**

You can refer to [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_use-of-the-pythonpath-variable) to understand the effects of these two configurations.